# Actions on Google responds with "Sorry, I didn't get any response."

Tags: firebase, google-api, actions-on-google

I am following this code lab [Facts about You: Build a conversational app for the Google Assistant](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/assistant-apiai-nodejs/#4)

I had it working once but must have done something wrong because now all.  To be 100% clear i have deleted everything on my pc downloaded the code from Git again deleted the project in actions console deleted the project in api.ai.   This is the result of a completely new install.  **I have not changed anything in the code lab.**

> "Sorry, I didn't get any response."

The request apears to be sending corectly

From actions test:

```
{
  "conversationToken": "CiZDIzU5Ym...",
  "debugLevel": 1,
  "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "mockLocation": {
    "city": "Mountain View",
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": 37.421980615353675,
      "longitude": -122.08419799804688
    },
    "formattedAddress": "Googleplex, Mountain View, CA 94043, United States",
    "zipCode": "94043"
  },
  "query": "tell me about cats",
  "surface": "GOOGLE_HOME"
}
```

Received in fire-base

```
 [{"name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"}]},"inputs":[{"rawInputs":[{"query":"tell me about cats","inputType":"VOICE"}],"arguments":[{"rawText":"tell me about cats","textValue":"tell me about cats","name":"text"}],"intent":"actions.intent.TEXT"}],"user":{"locale":"en-US","userId":"AETml1RzwqyijfbawqjZkRSXz-P1"},"device":{},"conversation":{"conversationId":"1504878811393","type":"ACTIVE","conversationToken":"[\"_actions_on_google_\",\"choose_fact-followup\"]"}}},"id":"3b97e239-346f-49a2-a106-96cfb6f69e92","timestamp":"2017-09-08T13:58:29.99Z","lang":"en","result":{"source":"agent","resolvedQuery":"tell me about cats","speech":"","action":"tell.cat.fact","actionIncomplete":false,"parameters":{},"contexts":[{"name":"_actions_on_google_","parameters":{"category.original":"headquarters","category":"headquarters","facts":{"content":{"headquarters":["Google has over 10 fitness facilities in its main campus."],"history":["Google was founded in 1998.","Google was founded by Larry Page and Sergey Brin.","Google went public in 2004.","Google has more than 70 offices in more than 40 countries."]}}},"lifespan":98},{"name":"actions_capability_audio_output","parameters":{},"lifespan":0},{"name":"google_assistant_input_type_voice","parameters":{},"lifespan":0},{"name":"choose_cats-followup","parameters":{},"lifespan":2}],"metadata":{"intentId":"14df3938-3776-477c-811c-d1758ecd15cb","webhookUsed":"true","webhookForSlotFillingUsed":"false","nluResponseTime":19,"intentName":"choose_cats"},"fulfillment":{"speech":"","messages":[{"type":0,"speech":""}]},"score":1},"status":{"code":200,"errorType":"success"},"sessionId":"1504878811393"}
```

Response returned to actions

```
{
  "audioResponse": "//NExAARAA...",
  "conversationToken": "CiZDIzU5Ym...",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "response": "Sorry, I didn't get any response.",
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElements": []
  }
}
```

I must be missing something.   Firebase is receiving the request its just not responding correctly.

training image

[image]

Comment: In your API.AI agent, what do you see in the Training logs?

Comment: image uploaded thats the last one

Comment: I am getting the same error. My app was is production for 1 month but from today I am seeing Sorry, I didn't get any response.
@DalmTo is it working for you now ?

Comment: We are have a bug in the Actions Platform that might be causing this. We are testing a fix and hope to have that rolled out soon.

Comment: @LeonNicholls its working now.

Answer (score 2):

That error on appears if your web hook doesn't provide a response to the assistant.  The cloud function has been triggered or has timed out and not returned the JSON back to assistant to parse.  Check to see what the output of the cloud function is and check it against the API.AI web hook format here https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/v1/apiai-webhook

It should look something like this:

```
{
  "speech": "...",  // ASCII characters only
  "displayText": "...",
  "data": {
  "google": {
      "expect_user_response": true,
      "is_ssml": true,
      "permissions_request": {
         "opt_context": "...",
         "permissions": [
            "NAME",
            "DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION",
            "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
          ]
      }
    }
    },
   "contextOut": [...],
}
```

Comment: Seeing as i am following Googles official code lab that you TA'ed i would assume the code is correct.    I am leaning towards a setup issue of somekind

Answer (score 2):

I think this is something on the Google's end. My application have been running on production for more than a week. Based on the logs everything was fine till 6 hours ago but since that the users don't get any answer back.
If I request on the API.AI the response is okay so it's not the firebase/fullfillment causing the issue.

Checked other applications some had the same problem some had no problem at all. Not sure what we can do here.

Comment: If this is the case then i am going to cry

Comment: Interestingly I number of other actions I have are also responding the same way so I'd say it's maybe something on Google's end.

Comment: For me it has been fixed from itself after like 12 hours so it was on the Google's side.

Answer (score 1):

Errors like this are usually caused by a syntax error or other problem in your Firebase Function after you've updated it. There are a few good approaches to diagnosing problems like this:

1. Check the Firebase function log. If there is an error, it will almost certainly show up here.

   From the command line you can use `firebase functions:log` to see the most recent logging messages. You can also use the console to view the logs by going to console.firebase.com, selecting the project, selecting Functions, and then the Logs tab.
2. If there isn't an error, it becomes more of a logic problem. Adding your own logs via `console.log()`, `console.info()`, or `console.error()`
3. Many times the logs will indicate the function is timing out after 60 seconds when you think you're returning things by then. Make sure you are completing any callbacks and calling `assistant.ask()` or `assistant.tell()` (or one of their cousins) to make sure they're being called.

Comment: As i mentioned there is no error in firebase as the response is returend.  debug in the actions on google test app is ""textToSpeech": "Okay, here's a headquarters fact. Google has over 30 cafeterias in its main campus. Would you like to hear another fact?""    Remember this is pure code lab I have not updated it or made any changes to Googles code lab

Comment: Firebase says:  "Function execution took 113 ms, finished with status code: 200"   So its not timing out, and 200 is a success code

Answer (score 0):

After posting a question on the [Google+ actions group](https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton/posts/ZiZG1WjTceX).  I got a response back from [Google](https://plus.google.com/+LeonNicholls/posts/CWkAs9rnDpZ).

> Actions Bug There is currently a bug in the Actions Platform that
>   might result in unexpected error messages when running your apps.
>
> We are currently testing a fix and hope to have that rolled out soon.

As of 10 minutes ago it is working again.   The code was correct all along.