# Actions with webhook is responding : "Sorry, I didn't get any response."

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have my action running in productions for a month. There was no update made to webhook and api.ai side. But from this morning I am getting 
"

> Sorry, I didn't get any response."

And its not just me, I found another thread where people are getting same error. 
[Actions on Google responds with "Sorry, I didn't get any response."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46118354/8413869)

Is there any new changes from google that have been made that I am not aware of ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine for me. There was some issue on google side.